Variable does'nt exist error while pushing the source code to the scratch org
I have tried to push the source code to my scratch org using this command  sfdx force:source:push
I'm getting component failures and deployment is getting failed below are the errors

Variable doesn't exist
In the field: field - no CustomField
Parent entity failed to deploy


@Tushar Jadav Thanks for formatting, solution for this question is appreciated.

We're going to need more information to help you. Your question suggests that you have an improperly formatted CustomField file, but without seeing some code around the line where the error occurred, as well as the full error message list, we can't really provide a definitive solution. Please [edit] your question to include more details.
